# How to create dynamic compose navigation graph?

Tags: android, navigation, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I've a requirement to create a navigation where the flow is completely depends on the API response. Sometimes it could be A->B->C->D->E or B->C->D->E or A->B->C->E. Already implemented the same stack management with `ArrayDeque` which is working fine. But want to replace with navigation compose.

I know we can change the `startDestination` in navigation graph. Is it possible in jetpack compose? Also, I want to make it from `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy in Compose.
Haven't tested this, but this mostly would work.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        MyTheme {
            MyApp(
                finishActivity = {
                    finish()
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApp.kt**

```
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(
    finishActivity: () -> Unit,
) {
    MyAppView(
        activityViewModel = activityViewModel,
    )
}
```

**MyNavGraph.kt**

```
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(
    activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel,
) {
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = activityViewModel.getStartDestination(),
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.name,
        ) {
            HomeScreen(
                activityViewModel = activityViewModel,
            )
        }
        // Other composables
    }
}
```

`activityViewModel.getStartDestination()` would make a network call a get the starting destination.

Add a comment if there are any issues with this.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work for a network call, as it would then be asynchronous, and therefore the value wouldn't be available when the nav host needs it.